# How to right-align text in an Android TextView or EditText?

Tags: android, alignment, android-edittext, layout-gravity

I have an EditText in my application. I want to align the text in it to the right instead of the default left. I tried adding

```
android:layout_gravity="right"
```

but this doesn't seem to work. any other suggestions please?

Answer (score 135, accepted):

You should use `android:gravity="right"`. `layout_gravity` is for the view (EditText) alignment against the container.

Comment: It's odd that the hint stops working once you do this gravity=right

Comment: For people with web experience. android:gravity works like text-align:center and android:layout_gravity:left|bottom   works like float:left|bottom

Answer (score 2):

You may use `android:layout_alignParentRight="true"` to align the EditText's right edge to its parent's right edge. Also, if you really want to use the `layout_gravity` or `gravity` attributes, check out this [article](http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/14/how-to-position-views-properly-in-layouts/) that discusses the proper use of them.

Answer (score 1):

You can jst set property for edit text in property window i.e. Gravity to right or by adding code of lin e in xml file of UI : android:gravity="right"

Answer (score 0):

**layout**_gravity means that you are specifying the **layouts** attribute, not the element inside. In some conditions, such as layout_width and layout_height is wrap_content, layout specifications can give what you want about the element inisde your layout, since the boundries of the layout and the element (not element**s**) are the same..

Answer (score 0):

use layout width and height as wrap content inside relative layout :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="64dp"
        android:layout_height="64dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:paddingEnd="16dp"
        android:paddingStart="8dp"
        tools:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:paddingRight="16dp"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/todo" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/icon"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:lines="1"
        android:paddingTop="8dp"
        tools:text="Google"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/last_used"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:paddingTop="8dp"
        tools:text="Last used: yesterday at 18.54" />
</RelativeLayout>
```