# Hint Alignment to the right of password EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext, right-to-left

I'm working on and activity with arabic language. I want the hint of the username and password to start from the right and I have no problem f typing started from the left but in my UI I want the hint to be of the right side. But when I'm adding the inputType for the EditText the hint moves to the left.I tried solving it programmatically but it didn't work.

Java

```
    EditText password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input_password);
    password.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT);
```

XML

```
<EditText
            android:id="@+id/input_password"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:hint="كلمة المرور"
            android:textColorHint="#FFFFFF"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:background="@null"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="20dp"/>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [right align EditText android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5698305/right-align-edittext-android)

Answer (score 9):

This is a bug in the Android Framework, for EditText fields in Android 4.4+ : https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37082815 or https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=201471. As of July 2016, it is currently unsolved.

However there is a way to workaround it:

- To make the hint display properly on the right (in right-to-left/RTL mode), you must **remove** the InputType property `textPassword` (`InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD`), when there is no text entered.
- To retain the password entry field behaviour of showing dots to conceal typed text, you must **dynamically enable** `InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD`, when the first character is entered in. And it must be reset when all characters are deleted.
- To prevent the UI glitch of Latin character input (LTR text like "abc123") jumping to the left or disappearing altogether, you must **explicitly set textDirection to RTL**.

Here are the details:

Pre-requisite for your `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<application
    ...
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    ... >
</application>
```

Your XML Layout contains:

```
     <EditText
        android:id="@+id/password"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:hint="סיסמא"
        ... />
```

Java code with workaround bug fix:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.login_fragment_layout, container, false);
    final EditText password = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.password);

    // Workaround https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37082815 for Android 4.4+
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT && isRTL(getActivity())) {

        // Force a right-aligned text entry, otherwise latin character input,
        // like "abc123", will jump to the left and may even disappear!
        password.setTextDirection(View.TEXT_DIRECTION_RTL);

        // Make the "Enter password" hint display on the right hand side
        password.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS);
    }

    password.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        boolean inputTypeChanged;

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {}

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            // Workaround https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=201471 for Android 4.4+
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT && isRTL(getActivity())) {
                if (s.length() > 0) {
                    if (!inputTypeChanged) {

                        // When a character is typed, dynamically change the EditText's
                        // InputType to PASSWORD, to show the dots and conceal the typed characters.
                        password.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT |
                                InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD |
                                InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS);

                        // Move the cursor to the correct place (after the typed character)
                        password.setSelection(s.length());

                        inputTypeChanged = true;
                    }
                } else {
                    // Reset EditText: Make the "Enter password" hint display on the right
                    password.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT |
                            InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS);

                    inputTypeChanged = false;
                }
            }
        }
    });

    return view;
}

public static boolean isRTL(Context context) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
        return context.getResources().getConfiguration().getLayoutDirection()
                == View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL;
        // Another way:
        // Define a boolean resource as "true" in res/values-ldrtl
        // and "false" in res/values
        // return context.getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.is_right_to_left);
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

It should work like this:

[image: Video screenshot, Arabic: Hint on right, password typed on right]

Answer (score 8):

Use Gravity Attribute to Adjust the Hint for EditText

```
        <EditText
        android:id="@+id/input_password"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:hint="كلمة المرور"
        android:textColorHint="#FFFFFF"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:background="@null"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="20dp"/>
```

Answer (score 8):

This one works fine for me

> android:textAlignment="viewStart"

The hint direction will be at the correct side

Answer (score 4):

add gravity `right` try this way

```
<EditText
            android:id="@+id/input_password"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:hint="كلمة المرور"
            android:textColorHint="#FFFFFF"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:background="@null"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:gravity="right"/>
```

if your API level 17 and higher you can use

```
android:textDirection="anyRtl"
```

Answer (score 3):

For AppCompatEditText edit text gravity start worked for me

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText
        ......
        android:hint="كلمه السر"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:gravity="start"
       .............../>
```

This will work only above api 16

you can also try, Where you must have stored your current language  I used this library com.akexorcist:localizationactivity

```
if(currentLanguage.country.toLowerCase() == "arabic"){
        etPassword.gravity = GravityCompat.END
}else{
        etPassword.gravity = GravityCompat.START
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use 'gravity' attribute:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/input_password"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:hint="كلمة المرور"
    android:textColorHint="#FFFFFF"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:background="@null"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="20dp"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can fix it by adding `\u202B` to the Hebrew/Arabic (or any other RTL language) text .

Example:

```
<LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <EditText android:hint="Enter a number..." android:id="@+id/editText"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:inputType="number"/>

    <EditText android:hint="\u202Bהכנס מספר..." android:id="@+id/editText2"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:inputType="number"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Sadly it seems it doesn't get shown on the layout preview, but it worked for me on a real device. Wrote about it [**here**](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/124606481)

Answer (score 0):

Here my solution (workaround) for editText with type = password. Work on Android 5, Android 6.

```
edittext_password = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.edittext_password);
            if (RTLUtils.isLeftToRightLanguage()) {
                edittext_password.setGravity(Gravity.START);
            } else {
                // Force a right-aligned text entry, otherwise latin character input,
                // like "abc123", will jump to the left and may even disappear!
                edittext_password.setTextDirection(View.TEXT_DIRECTION_RTL);
                // Make the hint display on the right hand side
                edittext_password.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS);
            }
            edittext_password.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                    isLeftToRight = RTLUtils.isLeftToRightLanguage(charSequence.toString());
                }

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
                    if (editable.length() > 0) {
                        isLeftToRight = RTLUtils.isLeftToRightLanguage(editable.toString());
                        if (isLeftToRight) {
                            edittext_password.setGravity(Gravity.START);
                            edittext_password.setTextDirection(View.TEXT_DIRECTION_LTR);
                            edittext_password.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS);
                            // Move the cursor to the correct place (after the typed character)
                            edittext_password.setSelection(editable.length());
                        } else {
                            //edittext_password.setGravity(Gravity.END);
                            edittext_password.setTextDirection(View.TEXT_DIRECTION_RTL);
                            // When a character is typed, dynamically change the EditText's
                            // InputType to PASSWORD, to show the dots and conceal the typed characters.
                            edittext_password.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT |
                                    InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD |
                                    InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS);
                            // Move the cursor to the correct place (after the typed character)
                            edittext_password.setSelection(editable.length());
                        }
                    } else { // empty text
                        if (!RTLUtils.isLeftToRightLanguage()) {
                            // Must be in this order (first setInputType then setTextDirection)
                            edittext_password.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS);
                            edittext_password.setTextDirection(View.TEXT_DIRECTION_RTL);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });

  public static boolean isLeftToRightLanguage() {
        Bidi bidi = new Bidi(Locale.getDefault().getDisplayLanguage(), Bidi.DIRECTION_DEFAULT_LEFT_TO_RIGHT);
        if (bidi.isLeftToRight()) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public static boolean isLeftToRightLanguage(String text) {
        Bidi bidi = new Bidi(text, Bidi.DIRECTION_DEFAULT_LEFT_TO_RIGHT);
        if (bidi.isLeftToRight()) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

And here result: (Arabic soft keyboard)

[image]

and English soft keyboard:

[image]